# Rails cancan (roles with weight)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have the following questions regarding CanCan:

If I have different roles for users and each one has a weight (their id), can I have also different resources with their corresponding role?

Is it possible to grant access to each resources only if the weight of the user is greater than or equal to the resource weight? For example:

### Roles:

- Admin => 3
- Writer => 2
- Reader => 1
- Basic => 0

### Example for Question 1:

Resources:

Resouce1 has role Writer

And then, only the users with role Admin or Writer can access

### Example for Question 2:

Resouce2 => 0

All user has acces to Resource2

Rule
    (if current_user.role_id < resource.role_id) can't not see the resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can. Cancan can be configured easily to do just this. I recommend the Railscast by Ryan Bates http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

It is his gem actually. But he explains it very well and gives you a good start for what you're wanting to do.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :update, Resource do |r|
      r.resource_weight <= user.role_weight
  end
end
```

EDIT: Attached is some basic idea code. Not functional yet obvioust but gives you an idea. The rails cast will help understand it.

Comment: Thank you!!!!, I will try it but if I need any help I will post again. Regards!!!